# Algebraic Topology: Hatcher, Example 1.43, Page 74

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology, in the first sentence of example 1.43 he states:
$$
\text{The Antipodal map of $S^n$, $x\to -x$, generates an action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $S^n$ with orbit space $\mathbb{R}P^n$.}
$$How do we know that the action generated is $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Applying the action twice fixes the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to repeat what Prospect mentioned. Since applying multiplication by $-1$ twice gives you the identity, then the group involved must be $\langle a | a^2=e \rangle$ which is just $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

If you need to check this is actually a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action is now easy (checking the axioms etc.).

Comment: Why *must* the group involved be $\mathbb{Z}/2$? I could define a $\mathbb{Z}/4$-action on $S^n$ in much the same way, no?

Comment: You could, and depending on what you do you may end up with a Lens Space in that case. In this case though, the Hatcher defines a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action.